# How to avoid closing app before test ios appium

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

This is the problem
I have noticed that when i run my tests, the app is closed then relaunched, i want a way to stop test from closing app and just starting test in the screen i am currently in, lets say if i am in settings screen, and i want to validate some stuff here, when i launch my test, the app is closed and it is open in home screen, so i have to add steps to navigate to settings, but i want to start my test in settings, even for testing this would be way faster.
I have tried using bundle id, the noReset = true and fullReset = false capabilities but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself
add capability

```
autoLaunch = False
```

this resolves the issue.
thanks